# Not authorized to control networking - 13.10

Tags: networking, 13.10

Just like in "[Not authorized to control networking](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304159/not-authorized-to-control-networking)" , I am unable to switch networks from the menubar icon.  I followed the recommendations in that question (add myself to a `netdev` group), but the problem remains.

I have Ubuntu 13.10, though.  Has the required group name changed?  Or any other ideas?