# Loosing user permissions after upgrading Kubuntu 14.04 to 14.10

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kubuntu

Yesterday I've upgraded my Kubuntu 14.04 to 14.10 thinking it would be safe to do so right now.
The upgrade proceeded as expected but somehow my user account apparently lost admin rights.

If I try to connect Wifi I get **"Not authorized to control networking"** That's about the same as described here: [Not authorized to control networking](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304159/not-authorized-to-control-networking). The solution described there doesn't help.

If I go to system settings to try to create a new user account I see immediately a message on top of the screen telling me that I can't save the settings. The same problem happens if I try to change the login screen.

Shutting down or restarting the computer in the regular way is also impossible and only throws me back to the login screen.

There's nothing disturbing in dmesg or any other relevant logfile I can think of.

I've issued the command 'id' in the terminal and this gives a normal list as far as I can tell.

I've checked the sudoers file and it looks completely normal.

In recovery mode I've tried the command `adduser myusernamehere sudo` and it says my username is already in the sudo group.

I've found out the wired network connection still works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going ro answer my own question.

This appears to be a recurring bug which has been reported on Launchpad back in 2013. Every version of ubuntu since is affected by this but not everyone sees the error. On the moment I write this (march 2015) there's no permanent solution, however there are workarounds to solve the problem.

For Ubuntu 14.10 the problem appears to be related to the package **ulatencyd**. Removing this package causes the error to disappear in my situation. If I recall correctly I've installed this package manually on a certain moment in time so it does not belong to a standard install and therefore this might not affect everyone.

More details about this bug and how to solve it in different Ubuntu versions can be found at: `https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-desktop-privileges/+bug/1240336`